# Optimization jquery code

Tags: jquery

How do I optimize the code below? In less lines.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".a1").hide();
jQuery(".a").click(function(){
    jQuery(".a1").toggle();
});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".b1").hide();
    jQuery(".b").click(function(){
        jQuery(".b1").toggle();
    });
    ...
```

...

Edit. Add my Html code.

```
<ul class="bg">
<li class="a">Text</li>
<li class="a1"><a href="#">Text</a></li>
<li class="a1"><a href="#">Text</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="bg">
<li class="b">Text</li>
<li class="b1"><a href="#">Text</a></li>
<li class="b1"><a href="#">Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: can you show as the corresponding html-markup?

Comment: please show your html code also.

Comment: Edit. I add html code.

Comment: sugest we move this post to code review

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on code-review.

Comment: @user4758595, the thing the code does and the thing you intend to do are not necessarily the same thing. When optimizing, I am always taking into account the exact thing the code aims to achieve. Also, optimization not necessarily means line number reducing. Mainly, there are two types of optimization: storage optimization and performance optimization. Storage optimization reduces the space used and performance optimization increases the speed of the code. What do you want to achieve with the code and what do you intend to optimize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery(".bg").find('li:has(a)').hide(); //hide all list-elements 
                                            //containing an anchor element

    jQuery(".bg > li:first-child").click(function () { //trigger click
                                                       // on the first list-element
        $(this).siblings('li').toggle(); //toggle all other list-elements
    });

});
```

It depends strongly on your provided html-markup, as it checks if there are `a`-tags inside the list-elements, which should be shown on click. But you can expand your existing markup with no need to change something or add additional data to it.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qkxvy5dL/)

**Reference**

[:has()](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

[:first-child()](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

[.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: @user4758595 please have a look at your console: `TypeError: $ is not a function`, have a look at [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) article

Answer (score 1):

use below code

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/xy896eu7/1/)

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".bg").find('li:not(:first)').hide();  // hide all li inside .bg expat  expat first.
   jQuery(".bg").find('li:first').click(function(){  // click event on first li
     $(this).nextAll('li').toggle(); // toggle other li expat first
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You can make use of `siblings()` to toggle `li`s

```
$(function(){
 $('.bg').find('li:first').siblings('li').hide();
  $('.bg').find('li:first').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('li').toggle();
 });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xy896eu7/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for more than one `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` call.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".a1, .b1").hide();
  jQuery(".a").click(function() {
    jQuery(".a1").toggle();
  });
  jQuery(".b").click(function() {
    jQuery(".b1").toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: click event is not on a1 b1 its  .a .b.

Comment: repeat same pattern 20 times and you have to repeat code blocks 20 times. This solution isn't much of an improvement from OP code

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
 $('ul.bg li:first').siblings().hide();
 $('ul.bg li:first').on("click", function(){
  $(this).siblings().toggle();
 })
})
</script>
```

Try this and let me know if that helps you

Comment: what if a and b is up tp a50,b50 ? how to hide all that element?

Comment: Try this - $('ul.bg li:first').siblings().hide(); if that works

Comment: if that works, use the same selector $('ul.bg li:first').click()